# Emailing from ASP.NET using Office 365 Online Exchange

Tags: asp.net, email, smtpclient

Trying to send email from asp.net application.
Emailing to server address: `Smtp.office365.com`
Port - `587`
Connection Security - `STARTTLS`
I have SMTP user name and SMTP password.

Fails to send email.

The code uses the SmtpClient, as follows:

```
String userName = "name@example.com";
String password = "Password";

MailAddress RecipientEmail = new MailAddress(EmailTo);
MailAddress SenderEmail = new MailAddress(cEmailFrom);
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(SenderEmail, RecipientEmail);
msg.Subject = "Test";
msg.Body = "This is a test";
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com:587");
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password);
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Send(msg);
```

The error message: Failure sending email.  No other information.

But if I specify the port:
    client.port = 587
instead of adding it to the host name, I get a very long error:

Transaction failed. The server response was: 5.2.0 
 STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message. 16.55847:BC110000, 17.43559:0000000094000000000000000100000000000000, 20.52176:140FBF85130010100A00D231, 20.50032:140FBF85831710100A00E231, 0.35180:86260000, 255.23226:0A00C931, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:0E000000, 255.31418:0A000000, 16.55847:DC000000, 17.43559:0000000088010000000000001E00000000000000, 20.52176:140FBF85130010109F260000, 20.50032:140FBF8583171010A4260000, 0.35180:0A00D330, 255.23226:A9260000, 255.27962:0A000000, 255.27962:32000000, 255.17082:DC040000, 0.27745:B3260000, 4.21921:DC040000, 255.27962:FA000000, 255.1494:0A007530, 0.37692:02010480, 0.44092:00000000, 0.40348:02010480, 0.34608:04000100, 0.55056:00000000, 0.42768:302E3134, 0.56112:31393A44, 0.52807:30363031, 4.33016:DC040000, 7.40748:010000000000010B2D343438, 7.57132:000000000000000037323032,

What is missing?

Comment: That's not even close to all of the code. How do you build the message? How do you set the credentials? And what error do you get when you run this?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn  I have been trying to update my initial post but the browser (IE 11) keeps hanging.  Sorry.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn  I edited my initial post.

Answer (score 3):

The important part from the error is the phrase "`SendAsDenied`".

Office 365 won't let you use your account on their smtp servers to send e-mail messages from someone else's address. *You just can't do it.* The closest you can get is in cases of organizational domain accounts, you can sometimes have service accounts within the organization that can be delegated to send on behalf of other users within the organization's domain.

If you need to do more than that, you must manage your own smtp server... and let me tell you, that's a whole other can of worms, requiring an ability to understand and configure some or all of rDNS, SPF, DKIM, Domain-Keys, and DMARC.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I understand and agree with your suggestion. 

But what bothers me is why when I specify the port with the host name (e.g. "Smtp.office365.com:587") I get no detailed error. But when I remove the port # from the Smtp.office365.com and specify it as 
client.port = 587, I get a very different and long error message.
Does it make sense to you?